# No Thunderbolt support on Thinkpad L590 running Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, thinkpad, thunderbolt

When showing the Thunderbolt information on my Thinkpad L590 running Ubuntu 20.04 I get the information:

`No Thunderbolt support - Thunderbolt security level could not be determinded`

I have disabled secure boot as some people were saying on other discussions that this may be the cause of the problem, but it does not seem to help.

Any idea of how to fix this?

### Edit and answer

As a comment pointed out, the L490 does not support thunderbolt, contrarily to for example the T490. So that is the explanation...

Comment: Are you sure it does support Thunderbolt? I couldn't find any Lenovo L590 with Thunderbolt in a quick Google search...

Comment: Gosh, you are right, it only supports USB C, not thunderbolt ^^ . I was being confused by the fact that both ports look identical. Sorry for my mistake...

Comment: I think though as a side note that the 'error' message is confusing. Would be better that it says ```- the machine does not have a thunderbolt port``` or something like that... :)

Comment: PS: I wrote an answer as I do not want people to loose time looking at this, but you are the one who found the answer, so feel free to write the same / a similar answer to mine, and I will suppress my answer and accept yours instead :)

Comment: It actually _is_ the same physical connector - USB-C - which is very confusing. If you intended to connect a docking station with display output and charging capabilities to that port, the L590 does support it. Not Thunderbolt, but DisplayPort Alt Mode and USB Power Delivery.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details :) What do you mean with DisplayPort? Should I use the DisplayPorts on the laptop / screen / docker rather than USBC? :)

Comment: "DisplayPort Alternate Mode" (or DP Alt Mode) is a specification that allows sending DisplayPort signals via USB-C, e.g. to connect an external monitor. "USB Power Delivery" (or USB PD) is a specification that allows transferring a rather huge amount of power via USB-C, e.g. to charge the laptop. If you buy a docking station that supports both of those specifications, you can connect monitors, USB devices, Ethernet etc. and charge the laptop at the same time via a single USB-C port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a comment pointed out, the L series including L590 does not support thunderbolt, contrarily to for example the T series including T590. So that is the explanation...

I think though as a side note that the 'error' message is confusing. Would be better that it says `- the machine does not have a thunderbolt port` or something like that.